# How to iterate though an array in a dataframe column, and do a lookup in another dataframe - Scala, Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe (df1), which look something like this:

```
+-------------------------+
|foods                    |
+-------------------------+
|[Apple, Apple, Banana]   |
|[Apple, Carrot, Broccoli]|
|[Spinach]                |
+-------------------------+
```

and I want to do a look up in another dataframe (df2) that looks like this:

```
+------------------+
|food    |category |
+------------------+
|Apple   |Fruit    |
|Carrot  |Vegetable|
|Broccoli|Vegetable|
|Banana  |Fruit    |
|Spinach |Vegetable|
+------------------+
```

and have the resulting dataframe look like this:

```
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
|foods                    |categories                   |has fruit|
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
|[Apple, Apple, Banana]   |[Fruit, Fruit, Fruit]        |true     |
|[Apple, Carrot, Broccoli]|[Fruit, Vegetable, Vegetable]|true     |
|[Spinach]                |[Vegetable]                  |false    |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

How would I be able to do this in Spark/Scala? I am new to Scala, so an explanation of the code may be helpful as well.
Thank you!

---

This is the code I am currently working with, but I am getting a `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` error `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column`.

```
var schema = df1.schema("foods").dataType

def func = udf((x: Seq[String]) => {
    x.map(x => df2.filter(col("food") === x).select(col("category")).head().getString(0))
}, schema)

df1.withColumn("categories", func($"foods")).show()
```

I would appreciate some help. The code doesn't need to be clean. Thank you.

---

I've tried turning df2 into a Map, and changed the code a bit:

```
var mappy = df2.map{ r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1))}.collect.toMap

var schema = df1.schema("foods").dataType

def func = udf((x: Seq[String]) => {
     x.map(x => mappy.getOrElse(x, ""))
}, schema)

df1.withColumn("categories", func($"foods")).show()
```

However, now I get this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)

(((repeats)))
```

Sorry for the messy code. This is for analysis, not production. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared your input DataFrames like this:

```
// below import is needed for you to use toDF() method to create DataFrames on the fly.
  import spark.implicits._

  val df1 = List(
    (List("Apple", "Apple", "Banana")),
    (List("Apple", "Carrot", "Broccoli")),
    (List("Spinach"))
  ).toDF("foods")

  val df2 = List(
    ("Apple", "Fruit"),
    ("Carrot", "Vegetable"),
    ("Broccoli", "Vegetable"),
    ("Banana", "Fruit"),
    ("Spinach", "Vegetable")
  ).toDF("food", "category")
```

My simple solution using DataFrames and Aggregate Functions using groupBy can get you the desired output (as follows) :

```
// imports 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// code
  val df1_altered = df1
// explode() : creates a new row for every element in the Array
    .withColumn("each_food_from_list", explode(col("foods")))

  // df1_altered.show()
  val df2_altered = df2
    .withColumn(
      "has_fruit",
      when(col("category").equalTo(lit("Fruit")), true).otherwise(false)
    )
  // df2_altered.show()

  df1_altered
    .join(df2_altered, df1_altered("each_food_from_list") === df2_altered("food"), "inner")
//groupBy() : acts as the opposite of explode() by grouping multiple rows together as one based on a column; with the specified mandatory Aggregate function(s)
    .groupBy(col("foods"))
    .agg(
      collect_list(col("category")) as "categories",
      max(col("has_fruit")) as "has fruit"
    )
    .show(false)
// +-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
// |foods                    |categories                   |has fruit|
// +-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
// |[Apple, Apple, Banana]   |[Fruit, Fruit, Fruit]        |true     |
// |[Apple, Carrot, Broccoli]|[Fruit, Vegetable, Vegetable]|true     |
// |[Spinach]                |[Vegetable]                  |false    |
// +-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

#### EDIT: With duplicates present in First DataFrame, you can use an ID column that you generated and then groupBy with both columns

Have mentioned the 3 lines of code change as change1, change2 and change3 below:

```
// change1
val df1_with_id = df1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
// change2
  val df1_altered = df1_with_id
    .withColumn("each_food_from_list", explode(col("foods")))

  // df1_altered.show()
  val df2_altered = df2
    .withColumn(
      "has_fruit",
      when(col("category").equalTo(lit("Fruit")), true).otherwise(false)
    )
  // df2_altered.show()

  df1_altered
    .join(df2_altered, df1_altered("each_food_from_list") === df2_altered("food"), "inner")
// change3
    .groupBy(col("id"),col("foods"))
    .agg(
      collect_list(col("category")) as "categories",
      max(col("has_fruit")) as "has fruit"
    )
    .show(false)


//+---+-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
//|id |foods                    |categories                   |has fruit|
//+---+-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
//|0  |[Apple, Apple, Banana]   |[Fruit, Fruit, Fruit]        |true     |
//|1  |[Apple, Apple, Banana]   |[Fruit, Fruit, Fruit]        |true     |
//|3  |[Spinach]                |[Vegetable]                  |false    |
//|2  |[Apple, Carrot, Broccoli]|[Fruit, Vegetable, Vegetable]|true     |
//+---+-------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I just have one question, how would the code change if df1 had duplicates that can't be dropped? I tried adding an 'id' column to df1, and did groupBy(col("id")) instead, but this seems to drop the 'foods' column, which would be helpful to have in the final dataframe. Again, thanks so much!!! I was stuck on this simple problem for so long.

Comment: Right!, you can add an ID and then groupBy with both columns to get desired output, i have edited the answer as well.